# Why do we have the hyphen is in front of the string of mac-address

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fetch a list of mac addresses that have been stored in mssql.  The below is the output I got. as there are empty row in existing table rows, we are getting the 'None'

[ ('BC5369778427', ), ('=', ),('104B7DE14D95', ), (None, ), ('00505D915F99', ), (None, ),]

I want to filter this output for only mac address in the below format

My desire output is  should be BC-53-69-77-84-27 10-4B-7D-E1-4D-95  00-50-5D-91-5F-99

I tried the below python code:

```
cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur2 = t2.cursor()

cur2.execute("CREATE TABLE macauth9 (macaddress TEXT);") // creates the new table to insert after filtering
t2.commit()
mac = cur1.execute("select MACAddress from myorginal-table").fetchall() //fetches all the mac address from mssql
stringmac = str(mac)
stringmac = stringmac.replace("(", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace(")", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("'", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("'", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace(",", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("[None", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("]", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("=", "")
stringmac = stringmac.replace("r", "")


dil = '-'.join(stringmac[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(stringmac),2))
mag = repr(str(dil))
cur2.execute("INSERT INTO macauth9(macaddress) VALUES(%s);", (mag,))
t2.commit()
conn.close() # getting -BC-53-69-77-84-27-   -  -  -  -10-4B-7D-E1-4D-95-  -00-50-5D-91-5F-99-
t2.close() # output should be   BC-53-69-77-84-27 10-4B-7D-E1-4D-95  00-50-5D-91-5F-99
```

### After the above code, I am getting this:

---

'  -BC-53-69-77-84-27-   -  -  -  -10-4B-7D-E1-4D-95-  -00-50-5D-91-5F-99-

I just want to remove the hyphen in front of the mac address and hyphen where the row is empt(- - -):  expected outcome should be BC-53-69-77-84-27 10-4B-7D-E1-4D-95  00-50-5D-91-5F-99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query resulted in a list of tuples, but you are converting it to a string representation and then trying to manipulate that, which is the wrong way to go about this. Instead you can iterate over the list, ignore values that obviously aren't MAC addresses and process those that are.

Example code:

```
import re

output = [ ('BC5369778427', ), ('=', ),('104B7DE14D95', ),
           (None, ), ('00505D915F99', ), (None, ),]
for value in output:
     value = value[0] # extract from the tuple
     if value is None or len(value) < 2:
         continue # skip useless values
     # Use regular expressions to put a '-' after every 2 characters:
     mac_rep = re.sub(r'[^-]{2}', r'\g<0>-', value)
     mac_rep = mac_rep[:-1] # the above also puts '-' at the end, so remove it
     print(mac_rep)
```

I used a regex but your method using join works as well.

You can also create a list of formatted MACs in one line, if you are a lazy degenerate who doesn't care about readability:

```
[re.sub(r'[^-]{2}',r'\g<0>-',v)[:-1] for (v,) in output if v is not None and len(v) > 2]
```